# Forward and reverse proxy to tunnel ssh through Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, proxy, http-proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache 2.4 server (on Debian Jessie) with multiple websites running on it with and without SSL.

In the hotel where I am now, port 22 seems to be blocked, but I would like to connect to my servers to continue managing them. What I would like to achieve eventually is use Putty or normal linux `ssh` to connect to my server using port 443, through a subdomain of my domain, so something like: `ssh.mydomain.com:443`. Is this possible?

I googled this and found many different answers, and I don't seem to understand which of them is what I really want. [Here](http://mark.koli.ch/configuring-apache-to-support-ssh-through-an-http-web-proxy-with-proxytunnel)'s an example. I changed the example given there to port `443` but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName ssh.mydomain.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/empty

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^CONNECT [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ - [F,L]

  ## Setup proxying between youwebserver:8443 and yoursshserver:22

  ProxyRequests On
  ProxyBadHeader Ignore
  ProxyVia Full

  AllowCONNECT 22

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
  </Proxy>

  <ProxyMatch (ssh\.mydomain\.com)>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </ProxyMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Could you please provide advice and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does [wetty](https://github.com/krishnasrinivas/wetty) useful for you?

Comment: @7171u Unfortunately not. I would like ssh over Putty. Thanks for the suggestion though.